# using REGEXP_EXTRACT to gather data

Tags: sql-server

P2_PCM_C_L112_2011_00_1v
P2_PCM_L212_2012_00_1v
P2_PCM_L119_2011_00_1v
P2_ABB_C_L6712_2012_00_1v
P2_PCM_L17612_2014_00_1v

I would like to gather information like PCM or ABB  then the year so 2011 from the above using REGXP_EXTRACT
Could you suggest the code for this

Comment: there are some good examples here https://docs.data.world/documentation/sql/reference/functions/regexp_extract.html

Comment: You can't in SQL Server, it doesn't support Regex, let alone `REGXP_EXTRACT`. If you *must* use Regex in SQL Server, you'll need to implement CLR functions. A [Google](//google.com)/[Bing](//bing.com)/[DuckDuckGo](//duckduckgo.com)/etc will very likely yield you several results.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution.

It is based on XQuery. It allows us to tokenize the input string without using REGEX.

Even dynamic structure of tokens is not an issue:

- Code (PCM or ABB) is a 2nd token.
- Year position is dynamic (4 or 5), but it is always a 3rd token from the right.

At the end, we have a relational/rectangular resultset so we can easily query/filter it via `WHERE` clause.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (tokens VARCHAR(8000));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('P2_PCM_C_L112_2011_00_1v'),
('P2_PCM_L212_2012_00_1v'),
('P2_PCM_L119_2011_00_1v'),
('P2_ABB_C_L6712_2012_00_1v'),
('P2_PCM_L17612_2014_00_1v');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '_';

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT *
        , code = c.value('(/root/r[2]/text())[1]', 'CHAR(3)') 
        , token_year = c.value('(/root/r[last() - 2]/text())[1]', 'INT') 
    FROM @tbl
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
          REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
          ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t(c)
)
SELECT * FROM rs
--WHERE code = ... AND token_year = ...;
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------------------------+------+------------+
| ID |          tokens           | code | token_year |
+----+---------------------------+------+------------+
|  1 | P2_PCM_C_L112_2011_00_1v  | PCM  |       2011 |
|  2 | P2_PCM_L212_2012_00_1v    | PCM  |       2012 |
|  3 | P2_PCM_L119_2011_00_1v    | PCM  |       2011 |
|  4 | P2_ABB_C_L6712_2012_00_1v | ABB  |       2012 |
|  5 | P2_PCM_L17612_2014_00_1v  | PCM  |       2014 |
+----+---------------------------+------+------------+
```

Comment: Did you have a chance to try the proposed solution?